# How to set a jLabel unclickable in java

Tags: java, onclick, jlabel

I am using jLabels instead of jButtons. I need to set a jLabel unclickable inside a if condition.

```
if(customerId==0){
        lblCustomerName.setText("0");
        //Set the jLabel unclickable
    }
    else{

        //Set the jLabel clickable
    }
```

I have already tried

```
lblContinue.setEnable(false);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: The user can't normally interact with JLabels, other than by looking at them, so when you say you want the label to be "unclickable," what do you mean? Do you want a tiny Yoda to jump into the GUI and repel the mouse pointer with his tiny light saber when the user tries to click on your label?

Comment: No actually I want to do nothing when user clicks it though it has a onMouseClick event

Comment: Consider removing the mouse listener if you don't intend to use it for anything. Or if you insist on having a mouse listener, leave the onClick handler empty. However, if you create a tiny Yoda to admonish your users, please send me a screenshot for my collection.

Comment: is it possible you want `lblContinue.setFocusable(false)`?  I'm also not sure what's happening currently when a user clicks on your JLabel that you're trying to prevent.

Comment: Depending on your structure, you should simple set a flag true or false based on your needs and check the flag in the MouseListener. If you have multiple labels registered with a single MouseListener, you might be able to use the clientProperty property to maintain the flag win the component itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global boolean value switching the function on and off in the MouseListener.

```
    private void lblCustomerNameMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if(booleanIsTrue)
    {
      //Do the Code when click enabled  
    }
    else
    {
        evt.consume();
    }
}
```

or

You can remove and add the MouseListener

```
MouseListener[] mouseListeners = lblCustomerName.getMouseListeners();
    for (int i = 0; i < mouseListeners.length; i++) {
        lblCustomerName.removeMouseListener(mouseListeners[i]);
    }
```